# Execute a program using python on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to windows python. I am trying to run a command line tool using python. This tool will flash the firmware connecting to IP address of the machine. I could open cmd prompt and use the command

C:\ToolsSuite>sdi --ip 172.23.240.41 --fwdl "c:\BUILDS\firmware_image.zip
.This works for me very well.

But when I try to execute using the python script on windows, I am not able to do that. Python script looks like this.

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\ToolsSuite")
#os.system('cd c:\mydir')
os.system("sdi --ip 192.92.48.32 --fwdl C:\firmware_image.zip")

#subprocess.Popen(r'sdi --ip 192.92.48.32 --fwdl "c:\firmware_image.zip"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

The exception thrown is "Could not find file". I am not getting how to give the path of the firmware file when it is stored in some location, say for example 'C' drive or in some folder location of windows.

Comment: `os.system("sdi --ip 192.92.48.32 --fwdl C:\\firmware_image.zip")`

Answer (score 0):

If the `sdi` executable is in "C:\ToolsSuite", this should work:

```
subprocess.call(['sdi', '--ip 192.92.48.32', r'--fwdl "c:\firmware_image.zip"'])
```

Comment: @jonatan, no it's not. Because of the `r`, everything that resides inside the following string enclosed by the single quotes is considered a raw string without any escaping. Test it: `print r'--fwdl "c:\firmware_image.zip"'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a Windows command, you need to give the full path to the command.

You can try:

```
import subprocess    
import os.path

# C:\ToolsSuite>sdi --ip 172.23.240.41 --fwdl "c:\BUILDS\firmware_image.zip"
cmd = os.path.join("C:\\ToolsSuite", "sdi")
args = [cmd,
        '--ip', '172.23.240.41',
        '--fwdl', 'c:\\BUILDS\\firmware_image.zip']
subprocess.check_call(args)
```

Here, `check_call` is useful to replace non-zero exit code by an exception. Of course, you can also choose another function of the same [family](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).